# Handling large result set from mysql with limited memory

Tags: php, mysql, performance, memory, pdo

I have a large database that contains results of an experiment for 1500 individuals. Each individual has 96 data points. I wrote the following script to summarize and then format the data so it can be used by the analysis software. At first all was good until I had more than 500 individuals. Now I am running out of memory.

I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion on now to overcome the memory limit problem without sacrificing speed.

This is how the table look in the database

fishId assayId allele1 allele2

14_1_1   1       A       T

14_1_1   2       A       A

```
$mysql = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=aquatech_DB', $db_user, $db_pass);
$query = $mysql->prepare("SELECT genotyped.fishid, genotyped.assayid, genotyped.allele1, genotyped.allele2, fishId.sex, " .
"fishId.role FROM `fishId` INNER JOIN genotyped ON genotyped.fishid=fishId.catId WHERE fishId.projectid=:project");
$query->bindParam(':project', $project, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
```

So this is the call to the database. It is joining information from two tables to build the file I need.

```
 if(!$query){
    $error = $query->errorInfo();
    print_r($error);
} else { 
    $data = array();
    $rows = array();
    if($results = $query->fetchAll()){
        foreach($results as $row)
        {
            $rows[] = $row[0];
            $role[$row[0]] = $row[5];
            $data[$row[0]][$row[1]]['alelleY'] = $row[2];
            $data[$row[0]][$row[1]]['alelleX'] = $row[3];
        }
        $rows = array_unique($rows);
        foreach($rows as $ids)
        {
            $col2 = $role[$ids];
            $alelleX = $alelleY = $content = "";
            foreach($snp as $loci)
            {
                $alelleY = convertAllele($data[$ids][$loci]['alelleY']);
                $alelleX = convertAllele($data[$ids][$loci]['alelleX']);
                $content .= "$alelleY\t$alelleX\t";
            }
            $body .= "$ids\t$col2\t" . substr($content, 0, -1) . "\n";
```

This parses the data. In the file I need I have to have one row per individual rather than 96 rows per individual, that is why the data has to be formatted. In the end of the script I just write $body to a file.

I need the output file to be

FishId  Assay 1  Assay 2

14_1_1  A  T   A  A

```
$location = "results/" . "$filename" . "_result.txt";
$fh = fopen("$location", 'w') or die ("Could not create destination file");
if(fwrite($fh, $body))
```

Comment: Don't use `$results = $query->fetchAll()){` but fetch and process one row at a time, so you're reducing the size of $results in memory

Comment: I have found that the best performance is gained when you don't write to the file with EVERY operation. Depending on the length of the data, I often perform the write operation every 100-1000 rows. In your case, if memory is tight or the rows are very long, perhaps read 100 records for every write operation? (Touching the file is quite lengthy compared to reading the data normally).

Comment: @anotherlife . . . You may be able to do more of the work in the database.  You should edit your question with the input data and your desired output.

Comment: Hi Fluffeh, I think what you mean is to use LIMIT in the mysql call, is that correct? So I can check how many rows there are with SELECT COUNT and then perform the write operation every 500 rows?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of reading the whole result from your database query into a variable with fetchAll(), fetch it row by row:

```
while($row = $query->fetch()) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `fetchAll()` fetches the entire result in one go, which has its uses but is greedy with memory.  Why not just use `fetch()` which handles one row at a time?
2. You seem to indexing the rows by the first column, creating another large array, and then removing duplicate items.  Why not use `SELECT DISTINCT` in the query to remove duplicates before they get to PHP?

I'm not sure what the impact would be on speed - `fetch()` may be slower than `fetchAll()` - but you don't have to remove duplicates from the array which saves some processing.

I'm also not sure what your second `foreach` is doing but you should be able to do it all in a single pass.  I.e. a `foreach` loop within a fetch loop.

Other observations on your code above:

- the `$role` array seems to do the same indexing job as `$rows` - using `$row[0]` as the key effectively removes the duplicates in a single pass.  Removing the duplicates by `SELECT DISTINCT` is probably better but, if not, do you need the `$rows` array and the array_unique function at all?
- if the same value of `$row[0]` can have different values of `$row[5]` then your indexing method will be discarding data - but you know what's in your data so I guess you've already thought of that (the same could be true of the `$data` array)

Comment: Hi Steve, I can't SELECT DISTINCT because each row indexed by fishId contains one of the 96 data points for all the individuals. So I need them all, but in the output file I need all these 96 points in one row, that is why I used array_unique. So I could get a list of the individuals and then have the 96 data points for each of them displayed in one row rather than as 96 rows. I hope that makes sense. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: In that case fetch will be less memory intensive than fetchAll.

Comment: As you go through the rows add them to an array indexed by individual id and data point, eg $array[$individualid][$datapoint]