# Yield statment to fetch bulk of records from mysql

Tags: php, yield

I have a mysql table which has around 900k records. When I am trying to access all of the records using PHP -> Mysqli, program getting memory exhaust issue. Though I have increased memory limit, still seeing the same issue.

One of the solution would be yield statement.

So here is my attempt.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from push_notification";
$result = (yield $conn->query($sql));
while(yield $result->valid()){
        $result->current();
        $result->next();
}
```

The above code not getting executed. Triggering error.

This execution not for the display but for processing each record or specific record. So I may have to loop through all the records present in the table.

Even PDO/Mysqli throwing the same error as memory exhaust.

Has any body used yield along with Mysql data processing, it's going to be a great help.

Comment: Why not paginate results?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Do you have to use mysqli? with PDO you could iterate through results one by one (and possibly yield them)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23805071/handling-large-result-set-from-mysql-with-limited-memory

Comment: Thanks @matiit. I thought of knowing more about yield so framed above query with respect to mysqli.

I redefine my actual issue.

I am using PDO to process mysql. My first statement itself is exiting saying memory exhaust.

Here is code:

$obj = $pdo->query("select * from clients"); // pdo is an object, clients has around 900k records

For the above itself says memory exhaust.

I have even doubled the default memory using memory_limit. Still facing same issue. So thought of trying out 'yield'.

Let me know if I am missing out anything?